# Python script can't open zmq-module

Tags: python

I've a problem with a python-script. In a script, i have:

```
  import zmq
  from datetime import datetime
  import pytz
  import bottle
  import logging
  from bottle import response
```

But, when i run this script, i see:
ImportError: No module named zmq

I've also tried:
       import pyzmq

When i run: pip install pyzmq, it display's that the package already is installed.

But it doesn't works. The probleem arose after i have updated Python 2.6.x to Python 2.7. I think, the plugins are not included in the upgrade?????

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: off-topic! Try SO instead.

Comment: Please read http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: I think, this is not a problem with my script, but with Python.
I think this is the right place? This is an server-question! about: 'Server and Workstation operating systems, hardware, and software.'

Do you have an idea???

Comment: I've solved this by installing pip and the plugins again.